# «Оглода́ние» — есть такое слово?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, существительные

В одной из телепрограмм, рассказывающих о блюдах русской кухни, прозвучала такая фраза: ***оглода́ние*** царской птицы [лебедя].

Удивилась. Посмотрела в словарях — слово не обнаружилось.
Подскажите, существует ли такое слово? Правильно так говорить?

Comment: Вы же понимаете смысл, да?

Comment: По-моему, рассказчик пропустил в слове букву "б": обглодание.

Comment: Возможно, конечно, но слово "обглодание" в словарях тоже отсутствует.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В словарях (Ушаков, Ефремова и др.) есть исходный (для этого отглагольного существительного) *глагол* сов. вида **оглодать** (несов. огладывать). Это старая форма глагола "**обглодать**". Из басни Крылова ( http://scanpoetry.ru/poetry/5909 ):

> И в месяц до костей он друга оглодал.

Соответственно, если речь шла о поедании костлявой птицы, можно было так сказать.

Comment: Спасибо, _Alex_ander._ Ваши разъяснения очень помогли — и слово все-таки нашлось. В словаре Даля: **оглоданье.** https://books.google.ee/books?id=nVBoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA3561&lpg=PA3561&dq=%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=WjkJObkPjD&sig=ACfU3U2aMCilpxwsPFh32Oc8dooUgHqtMA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUgaa8v6joAhWME5oKHebaBWsQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5&f=false